# Solving a system of numerical equations from a truncated series

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion, coefficients

I have an equation of the following sort:

$$\sum_{s=0}^\infty c(s)f(s,x) = g(x), \tag{1}$$

where everything is real and $s$ is an integer. I know $f(s,x)$ and $g(x)$ numerically for any $s$ and any $x$.

I also know that both $c(s)$ and $c(s)f(s,x)$ die off as $s$ increases. My functions are fairly complex, but in order to provide a MWE I searched a bit and found the following series expansion:

$$\frac{x}{\log (1-x)} = -1 + \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{12} + \frac{x^3}{24} + ... \tag{2}$$

Since I cannot solve $(1)$ numerically for an infinite number of coefficients, I would like to truncate the series to some $s_\text{max}$, i.e. approximate:

$$\sum_{s=0}^{s_\text{max}} c(s)f(s,x) \sim g(x). \tag{3}$$

With my numerical data I can now set a system of ($s_\text{max} + 1$) equations and solve for the coefficients. However there are two problems: *(1)* the last coefficients before $s_\text{max}$ will be very inaccurate and may affect the front coefficients, *(2)* eq. (3) is not an exact equation so `Solve` may find no solution.

To illustrate problem *(1)*, take the example of eq. $(2)$ and try to solve numerically for the coefficients (see my script below). The two first coefficients are more or less okay, but the third one is already totally off. Increasing the number of coefficients does not help at all, as Mathematica unfortunately *does not know* that the coefficients decrease.

In order to solve that issue, I thought of the following idea: since I know that the last coefficients are small, I could instate a second cutoff $s_{\text{max},2}$ smaller than $s_\text{max}$ for which I set all the coefficients equal to zero. Unfortunately, doing that I cannot find any solution to the system of equations anymore.

For problem *(2)*, I am not sure but maybe I could use `NSolve` and specify a desired accuracy? I tried that but still no solution came out.

Any help would be much appreciated. I am not sure that this is actually solvable that way, it was an idea for a complicated problem that I am facing.

Here is the MWE:

```
g = x/Log[1 - x];
smax = 5;
lhs = Sum[c[s]*x^s, {s, 0, smax}];
xstart = .1;
xend = .9;
xstep = (xend - xstart)/smax;
syseq = Table[lhs == g, {x, xstart, xend,xstep}]; (* generates system of equations *)
Solve[syseq, {c[0],c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4], c[5]}]
realsol = N[{-1, 1/2, 1/12, 1/24, 19/720, 3/160}] (* exact coefficients for comparison *)
```

Comment: Is your actual problem also a Taylor series expansion? There's some stuff you can do in that case; otherwise, things aren't straightforward for e.g. Dirichlet or Lambert series.

Comment: @J.M. No, but for the context my actual problem is of the following form: $g(x,y) = A f_1 (x,y) + B f_2 (x,y) + \sum C(s) f_3 (x,y,s) + \sum D(s) f_4 (x,y,s) + \sum E(s) f_5 (x,y,s)$ where the sums run over $s$. I do know all the $f$'s analytically (they are very complicated), but the $g$ I can get only numerically.

Comment: You need a better example because your $f(x,s)=x^s$ is unrealistically simple. As I understood it, you need to expand $g(x)$ in terms of complicated functions. By the way, are $f_s(x)$ orthogonal?

Comment: @yarchik Yes it is not easy to come up with an example that is not too complicated and yet not too simple. I still think that the example has some value if you can solve it approximately purely numerically, i.e. without using any trick. Regarding the orthogonality relations, it is not clear to me. The functions I have are $\tanh^{-1}$ and hypergeometric functions, for example the easiest one is $f_1 (x,y) = 2 \tanh^{-1} (\sqrt{xy}) - \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{xy} (x+y)\ _2F_1 (1/2,2,5/2,xy)$. The other ones are all long sums of hypergeometric functions, often with a different power of $x$ in front.

Comment: The problem is that you do not define precisely how Eq.(1) should be fulfilled. It is important to keep in mind that you need a numeric (not analytic) approach. You already solve your problem by matching the values at 5 points. But maybe this is not your goal. Another possibility could be that the integral of deviation is minimized over some interval $R$: $\min_{c_s} \int_R dx |g(x)- \sum_s c_s f_s(x)|^2$.

Comment: @yarchik "You already solve your problem by matching the values at 5 points." Do I? That is precisely what I was trying to do with the example of eq. $(2)$, but I was not successful, because of the truncation. If I would have this working, I think I would be good to go.

Comment: Try to plot and you will see that $g(x)$ and $\sum_sc_sf_s(x)$ intersect at those points. Thus, you solve your goal.

Comment: @yarchik Yeah that's interesting. The plot is actually pretty good, it's even better than the Taylor expansion at this given order. But yeah, it seems like I cannot match the coefficients with the ones given in $(2)$, which would be the goal here. Of course there are many ways to expand a function, and I guess I did not realize that when starting with this idea.